# Deleting and creating an userform with the same name dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm actually coding to delete all the userforms of a project and recreate them by using a XML file.
The problem is that when I delete a userform and I want to recreate it with the same name, I get the following error `"Run-time error '75' - Path/File error"`.

I use this to delete userforms :

```
Application.VBE.VBProjects(iMyName).VBComponents.Remove VBComponent:=.Item(x)
```

Where **`iMyName`** is the project name and **`x`** the variable in my loop.
And just after I use:

```
Set ihm_f = .Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
ihm_f.Properties("Name") = "CA"
```

Where **`ihm_f`** is my new userform and `CA` the name of the previous Userform I deleted for example.
Do someone know how to do ?

Comment: How are you declaring `ihm_f`?

Comment: Yes `dim ihm_f as object`

Answer (score 0):

Try Saving the Workbook between Removing and re-Creating.
Works for me, but I would be interested to knows a better way.